# Can I access a C++11 std::map entry while inserting/erasing from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdmap

Can I access (without locking) an std::map entry while another thread inserts/erases entrys?

example pseudo C++:

```
typedef struct {
   int value;
   int stuff;
}some_type_t;

std::map<char,some_type_t*> my_map;   

//thread 1 does:
my_map.at('a')->value = 1;

//thread 2 does:
some_type_t* stuff = my_map.at('b');

//thread 3 does:
my_map.erase('c');

//I'm not modifying any elements T is a pointer to an previously allocated "some_type_t"
```

std C++11 says that all members should be thread safe (erase() is not const).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No no no no no!

`map::erase` modifies the links between the map entries and that messes with the search algorithm used in `map::at`. You can use the elements during an erase, but you can not execute the searching algorithm itself!

I've created an illustration program. On my machine this program sometimes print OK, sometimes throws a map exception - that means that the search is gone wrong. Increasing the number of reading threads make the exception appear more often.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <map>
#include <cassert>

std::map<int, int> m;

// this thread uses map::at to access elements
void foo()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    int lindex = 10000 + i % 1000;
    int l = m.at(lindex);
    assert(l == lindex);
    int hindex = 90000 + i % 1000;
    int h = m.at(hindex);
    assert(h == hindex);
  }
  std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
}

// this thread uses map::erase to delete elements
void bar()
{
  for (int i = 20000; i < 80000; ++i) {
    m.erase(i);
  }
}

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
    m[i] = i;
  }

  std::thread read1(foo);
  std::thread read2(foo);
  std::thread erase(bar);

  read1.join();
  read2.join();
  erase.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

No.  And yes.

Two or more threads can perform `const` operations on a map, where a few non-`const` operations also count (operations that return non-`const` iterators, hence are not `const`, like `begin` and similar stuff).

You can also modify the non-key component of an element of a `map` or `set` while other operations that do not read/write/destroy said element's non-key component run (which is most of them, except stuff like `erase` or `=`).

You cannot `erase` or `insert` or other similar non-const map operations while doing anything with `const` and similar map operations (like `find` or `at`).  Note that `[]` can be similar to `erase` if the element is added.

The standard has an explicit list of non-`const` operations that count as `const` for the purposes of thread safety -- but they are basically lookups that return `iterator` or `&`.

Answer (score 0):

No. std::map are not thread safe. Intel's thread building block (tbb) library has some concurrent containers. Check [tbb](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview.htm%20tbb)

Comment: That depends on your definition of thread-safe, which is not a clearly defined term. For example, `std::map` meets the thread-safety requirements of the C++ standard, so is "thread-safe", but those requirements do not allow concurrent reads/writes of a single object, so it's also not "thread-safe". It's best to avoid using that term unless you state exactly how you are using it.