Is it thread-safe if I modify an element and insert an element on same container(e.g. std::unordered_map) from different threads?
I have a container std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> myMap;,  and a mutex std::mutex myMutex.
When I try to access to myMap, I use myMutex like the codes below:
void insert(const std::string& Key)
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
  if(!myMap.contains(Key))
  {
    auto& v = myMap[Key];
    // do something to v to make it not empty
  }
}

std::vector<int>& get(const std::string& Key)
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
  static std::vector<int> empty; // this container will be read only
  if(myMap.contains(Key))
  {
    auto& v = myMap[Key];
    return v;
  }
  return empty;
}

Is it thread-safe if I try to modify the container
std::vector<int>& apples = get("Apple");
if(!apples.empty()) // check for existance
{
  //do something to apples
}

from one thread(I don't use myMutex when I try to change apples), and call the funtion
insert("AnotherApple");

from another thread?
In my case, I synchronize with insert and get, but I don't synchronize with them(especially insert, which will modify the unordered_map) when I do some change to the reference value (here is the container apples) of a specified key get from get. But I will use some other mutex(other than myMutex) to synchronize with these changes to prevent writes on the content of same key from different threads.
It seems that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994312/can-i-access-a-c11-stdmap-entry-while-inserting-erasing-from-another-thread, the first answer by Yakk - Adam Nevraumont says

You can also modify the non-key component of an element of a map or set while other operations that do not read/write/destroy said element's non-key component run (which is most of them, except stuff like erase or =).

and that the statement in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container


Elements of the same container can be modified concurrently with those member functions that are not specified to access these elements.


are both describing my case. But I am not really sure, can someone give me some clarification?
Edit : I am sorry about lacking of detail, here is a more detailed code. I try to do with exceptions as proposed by @Yksisarvinen though I am not familiar with it, so there may be some mistakes.
class myManager
{
public:
    myManager() = default;
    void insert(const std::string& id)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        if (!myMap.contains(id))
        {
            myMap[id];// if throw exception here, then nothing happen?

            try {
                mySeparateMutex[id];
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                myMap.erase(myMap.find(id));// need to erase element with Key==id from myMap to consistent with mySeparateMutex
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    std::tuple<std::vector<int>&, std::mutex&> get(const std::string& id, bool& ok)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        static std::vector<int> Empty;
        static std::mutex noMutex;
        ok = false;
        if (myMap.contains(id))
        {
            ok = true;
            return std::tie(myMap[id], mySeparateMutex[id]);// I think operator[] will throw nothing
        }
        return std::tie(Empty, noMutex);
    }
private:
    // assume we can only access directly to these private member by public member functions above 
    std::mutex myMutex;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> myMap;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::mutex> mySeparateMutex;
};

myManager instance;

void fun0(const std::string& id)
{
    bool isContain = false;
    auto [a, b] = instance.get(id, isContain);
    if (isContain)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(b);// this mutex for preventing writing/reading container of same key
        // do some change
        a.push_back(1);
        a.push_back(2);
    }
}
void fun1(const std::string& id)
{
    instance.insert(id);
}
int fun2(const std::string& id, int index)
{
    bool isContain = false;
    auto [a, b] = instance.get(id, isContain);
    if (isContain)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(b);
        if (index >= 0 && index < a.size())
        {
            // do some read
            return a[index];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    fun1("apple");
    std::thread a([]() {
        fun0("apple");
        });
    std::thread b([]() {
        fun1("apple");
        });
    std::thread c([]() {
        fun2("apple", 0);
        });
    std::thread d([]() {
        fun0("apple");
        });
    // there are some other threads call fun* with id=="banana",...

    a.join();
    b.join();
    c.join();
    d.join();
    // join other threads
    return 0;

}


I don't see any potential for data race here, but relying on such weak promises means anyone in the future (including you) will have a very hard time modifying this code. Any change is a risk to introduce a data race now. Also, insert() better have a strong exception guarantee, because otherwise you have a data race as-is.

please post a [mcve]. Details matter and if you only describe parts of your code rather than showing them, misunderstandings are likely to happen.

Since std::unordered_map is implemented as an array (i.e. buckets) of linked lists of pairs, then a potential rehashing would not change the address of the key-value pairs inserted into the container.  However, this property does not apply to all containers.  Consider boost::unordered_flat_map.  Since the insert function can trigger a rehash, there is no guarantee the std::vector<int>& returned by get is valid.

returning reference std::vector<int>&  to something what is synchronized is highly probable that there is a race condition in a code. Basically you are exposing without a lock, something what looks like something what should be protected. This is quite common mistake to return a reference to something synchronized. Problem is this depends on general logic of your code. Returning  const std::vector<int>& would be less suspsitios, but still this depends on whole logic of your code. Now I would say you have posible race.

Assuming you are doing modification on result of get then you have obvious race condition. Please provide more details.

@MarekR I've added a more detailed version code, would you mind reading it and give me some comment if there is mistakes.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai  I've added a more detailed version code, would you mind reading it and give me some comment if there is mistakes.

@Yksisarvinen I've tried to modify it with some exceptions-concerned code. Would you mind reading it and give me some comment if there is mistakes.

For completeness assuming that you have some
std::mutex myMutex;
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> myMap;

and then
int main() {
    insert("Apple");
    std::jthread t1([]() {
        std::vector<int>& apples = get("Apple");
        if(!apples.empty()) // check for existance
        {
            apples.push_back(70);
        }
    });
    std::jthread t2([]() {
        insert("Banana");
    });
}

There is no data race (neither logical so-called race-condition), because thanks to Iterator invalidation rules of std::unordered_map, references remain valid after the insertion, even if rehash happened (note that the same would not be true for iterators). It means that thread t2 is not touching the data used in thread t1, unless you would try to insert "Apple" again.
As a side note, I would rather synchronize the access to myMap on the application level, not inside insert, get functions. That way you can always decide which sync granularity level is required and avoid race-conditions.
EDIT after question edits
Your new code with class myManager doesn't have data races (apart from visual inspection I also checked it with Helgrind and DRD), however it would be very easy to introduce such a race, should the user of your code forget e.g. about locking the borrowed mutex.
If you later modify your code and e.g. add some myMap[id].push_back(3); in your insert method (AFTER the guarding if block), you will have a data race.
Returning std::tie(Empty, noMutex); is ultra-hacky and very easy to misuse, user can easily forget about boolean arg check and modify Empty vector, lock noMutex, which doesn't make sense semantically.
Your try-catch blocks are sceptical, you are focusing on the wrong problem. operator[] of unordered_map will throw only if constructors of Key or Value throw. Default std::vector and std::mutex constructors are both nothrow, only copy constructor of std::string can throw if allocation fails, which is imho highly unlikely.
So again, this particular example is "correct", but I recommend removing synchronisation from myManager and doing it on the user side. E.g. lock the mutex (not owned by myManager) inside your fun0, fun1, fun2.

Assuming he has multiple instances of t1 then apples.push_back(70); is obvoius race condition on std::vector

@MarekR yes, however in the question we have "if I try to modify the container (...) from one thread (...) and call the function (...) from another thread", so this particular case is fine.

It seems that you have already answered my question, what I really concern is exactly the validity of the reference of the non-key component of a certain key A when I try to modify the container with key other than A.  I give a more detailed version code, would you mind reading it and give me some comment if there is mistakes.

@0x314159 here you go; TL;DR don't do it like that.

I feel a bit confused again, why there is data race if I add myMap[id].push_back(3); in my insert method? When I try to modify myMap[id] in insert, it should be(?) the very first time I've added myMap[id] ( guaranteed by if statement?), it seems impossible for other thread to get the reference to myMap[id] at the same time since other threads will get the reference only through get, which is synchronized with insert.  Do you mean there might be some reordering (e.g. branch prediction) in insert, it will excute myMap[id].push_back(3); even myMap.contains(id)==true?

No, I meant if you add another push_back in the end of the method, after the guarding if block. Ofc now it seems stupid, but I can imagine this kind of mistake later during development.

You're right, if I want to modify myManager, I will look through it again and again to confirm. In my real project, the get function will only return a const reference to myMap[id] which is read-only, so no more mySeparateMutex, and reference to empty container represent both failure and myMap[id] that happens to be empty, no more IsContain. And I will only modify(initialize) myMap[id] in insert.  So I only lock insert and get here. I change the code for better understanding the reference will not race with the exact insert method even it is not const.

Another question if you don't mind, what do you mean by "focusing on wrong problem" about the try-catch? I've been rarely concerned about exception on my code( now I know it's dangerous ), so I don't understand what is the right concern on insert about exceptions, do you mean I don't need to use any try-catch here?

About try-catches I mean that in your example the only exception that could be thrown is from dynamic allocations e.g. std::bad_alloc if you run out of memory. So it's quite unlikely to happen, and if it does happen, your program is already in a big trouble. So, the try-catch around mySeparateMutex[id]; is only obscuring the code. The comments around all other map access statements are correct, they will not throw (unless allocation throws). I understand your idea of "strong exception guarantee", but I think it's a bit exaggerated (unless instead of int you have T that can throw).
